# Heroku, Cedar stack: What requests take up dyno time

Tags: java, caching, heroku, cloud, cloud-hosting

I have given some thought on how to calculate how many users I can handle with Heroku and one dyno.
But to figure it out I need some input.

And I must say that the official documentation isn't nice to navigate and interpreter so I haven't read it all. My complaints about it are that it doesn't describe things very well. Sometimes it describes old stacks, sometimes it's ruby specific, sometime it isn't described at all and so on.

So I need some input on how Heroku, Cedar stack, works regarding requests to make my calculations.

You are more than welcome to correct me on my assumptions as I am relatively new to dyno theory.

Lets say I have a controller that takes a request and calculate a JSON response in 10ms locally will I be able to serve 100request a second?

As I understand the cedar stack doesn't have a fronting caching solution, many questions arises.

1. Does static content requests take up dyno time?
2. Does transfer time count to request time.
3. Can one dyno solution transfer many response to a request at the same time if the request requires small CPU utilization.

Some of the question is intertwined so a combined answer or other thought is valued.

An example:

Static HTML page.

```
<HTML>...<img><css><script>...
AjaxCall //dyno processing time 10ms
AjaxCall //dyno processing time 10ms
AjaxCall //dyno processing time 10ms
AjaxCall //dyno processing time 10ms
...</HTML>
```

**Can I serve (1000ms / (10ms x 4)) = 25HTML pages a second?**

- This assumes that static content isn't provided by a dyno.
- This assumes that transfer time isn't blamed on the dyno.

If this isn't the case I would be a **catastrophe**. Lets say a mobile phone in Africa makes 10 request and have a 10sec transfer time then my App will be unavailable for over 1½ minute.

Comment: It's always a best practice to edge cache static assets on a CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only really answer the first question: Static assets most certainly do take up dyno time. In fact, I think it's best to keep **all** static assets, including stylesheets and JS on an asset server when using heroku's free package. (If everyone did that, heroku would benefit and so would you). I recommend using the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem to handle that. The Readme does explain that there are one or two, easily resolved, current issues.

Regarding your last point, sorry if I'm misinterpreting here, but a user in south africa might take 10 seconds to have their request routed to Heroku, but most of that time is probably spent trafficking around the maze of telephone exchanges between SA and USA. Your dyno is only tied up for the portion of the request that takes place inside Heroku's servers, not the 9.9 seconds your request spent getting there. So effectively Heroku is oblivious to whether your request is coming from South Africa or Sweden.

There are all sorts of things you can do to speed your app up: Caching, more dynos, Unicorn with several workers

Comment: Thanks for the insights. You didn't misinterpreted, actually you were spot on as I was afraid of Heroku's very slow response times outside USA was taking up dyno time. I will learn Scala with the Play framework so your recommendation of asset_sync may not suit me as it's for Ruby only? OT: It's a big drawback for playing around that you have to deploy to two servers, that removes much of the simplicity of only have a repo, with all content, and type git push.

Answer (score 2):

You're making two wrong assumptions. The good news is that your problem becomes much simpler once you think about things differently.

First off remember that a dyno is a single process, not a single thread. If you're using Java then you'll be utilizing many request threads. Therefore you don't have to worry about your application being unavailable while a request is being processed. You'll be able to process requests in parallel.

Also when talking about dyno time that refers to the amount of time that your process is running not just request processing time. So a web process that is waiting for a request still consumes dyno time since the process is up while it waits for requests. This is why you get 750 free dyno hours a month. You'll be able to run a single dyno for the entire month (720 hours).

As far as computing how many requests your application can serve per second the best way to do that is to test it. You can use New Relic to monitor your application while you load test it with JMeter or whatever your favorite load testing program is: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic